# How to build and run Ubuntu 16.04 kernel with a specific module?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, linux-kernel, embedded-linux, kernel-module

I installed Ubuntu 16.04 on Nvidia Tegra TK board (arm architecture). 
Then I connected touchscreen from STMicroelectronics STMPE to it.
But generic kernel does not include the module for this touchscreen.
So, I guess I need to rebuild the kernel.

What is the recommended way to do this?
Should I do it with make menuconfig or fakeroot debian/rules?
Please describe it in details, step by step.

Thanks!

Comment: This Q **may** be more appropriate on the S.E. related sites, either http://askubuntu.com or http://unix.stackexchange.com  (Unix & Linux).  Use the `flag` link at the bottom of your Q and ask the moderator to move it. Please don't post the same Q on 2 different sites. Please read  http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask and http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve before posting more Qs here. Good luck.

Comment: Not exactly, you need to build a driver for it. It indeed **might** require to rebuild entire kernel. By the way, driver might be also be present, but not exactly compatible with your model of touch screen.